# Having trouble processing a file from my documents in my code?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have searched for this around the web and here but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am simply trying get better with file processing and c++.

For practice I am trying to grab a text file from a game folder and make a copy of it.

Here is my code (that can't access the file).

```
#include <fstream>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()

{
    //define / open files
    ifstream my_input_file;
    ofstream my_output_file;
    string filepath = "C:/Users/David Laptop/Documents/my games/oblivion/RenderInfo.txt";
    my_input_file.open(filepath);


    if (my_input_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "opened\n";
        my_output_file.open("output_file.txt", ofstream::trunc);
        char c;
        my_input_file.get(c);
        while (my_input_file)
        {
            my_output_file.put(c);
            my_input_file.get(c);
        }

        my_input_file.close();
        my_output_file.close();


    }
    else
    {
        cout << "FAIL\n";
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This seemed to work with both text files and .ini files when in the project directory but I am having issues properly getting to other directiorys?

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a file in C++ outside of the working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093891/opening-a-file-in-c-outside-of-the-working-directory)

Comment: the file isn't being opened and thus not copied into output_file.txt

Comment: I think the problem is with the directory path not formatted correctly...I have very little experience with directories so that is my first guess.

Comment: [Do a `perror` and find out why you can't open the file.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid and it works - I tried it *with my own file* instead of yours, in the line

```
    string filepath = "C:/Users/David Laptop/Documents/my games/oblivion/RenderInfo.txt";
```

So *you have not* such **file** or *it is not* in the given **path** or you *have not* such **path**.

Correct it in that line and it will be OK.

> **Tip:** Find your file in Windows Explorer, press (and keep pressing) `Shift`) and right-click on this file. From the context menu then choose `Copy as path` and then paste it to your code. But be carefull - you have to change every backslash (`\`) to a forward slash (`/`) (as in your code) or use double backslashes (`\\`) instead of a single one.

Comment: wow... I am sorry, the file was "RendererInfo.txt" NOT "RenderInfo.txt"....I am slapping myself in the face but thanks for the help!

Comment: Super! I extended my answer with a tip how to *prevent similar typos* (in future).

Comment: Please consider to upvote my answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: MarianD sorry! I tried to but because I'm new here (less than 15 rep) I cannot...I promise I will come back though when I can give you an up vote :)

Comment: Just for the record... I came back eventually to give you the upvote XD - cheers

Comment: @DavidK, very nice from you, thanks! It is incredible to remember it for such a long period of time.