# how to print file to a differnt folder

Tags: c++, file, directory

```
std::string file = "Cell.txt";
myfile.open (file);
```

makes a file in current program folder. i dont want the files mixed with the program that is writing them.

```
std::string file = "Cell\\Cell.txt";
```

does nothing

```
std::cout << file << '\n';
```

prints Cell\Cell.txt

i even tried

```
std::string file = "\\Cell\\Cell.txt";
```

did not expect this to work, but tried it anyway

```
std::string file = "\\\\Cell\\\\Cell.txt";
```

i have done it before, and can not fine anything on web to help

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093891/opening-a-file-in-c-outside-of-the-working-directory

Comment: The file path must exist before opening the file. [Check out this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: not using windows

Comment: folder Cell does exist. have run program, made it, run program, deleted it, tried something different, ......

Comment: Consider using the new filesystem library in c++17 (or the experimental filesystem library in older versions of the standard) to do things like construct paths and create directories.

Comment: what is the new filesystem in -std=c++17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're not using windows, and yet you create paths like this:

```
std::string file = "Cell\\Cell.txt";
```

This isn't a file called `Cell.txt` in a directory called `Cell`, but a file called `Cell\Cell.txt` because backslash path separators are a windows-ism, and under other operating systems they're part of the directory or file name. Use a forward slash instead: `Cell/Cell.txt`.

Better yet, use the new C++ filesystem libraries to build your paths in a platform-independent sort of manner, and avoid this issue entirely.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
  auto path = fs::path("Cell") / fs::path("Cell.txt");

  std::cout << path.string() << std::endl;
}
```

This will output

> Cell\Cell.txt

under windows and

> Cell/Cell.txt

under linux, for example. You can also create directories using [create_directory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory).

(note: this works out of the box on windows under vs2017 and probably 2015, but under g++ you'll need to include an extra library at compile time, like this: `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -lstdc++fs`)

Comment: could not get #include <experimental/filesystem> to work, but changing \ to / and manually making folder, worked

Comment: @michaeleric which compiler are you using? name and version, if you can.

Comment: um, NetBeans     not sure     NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2        dont know where to look for which compiler it is using

Comment: @michaeleric It is probably using g++ underneath so there's no reason why it _couldn't_ work. I'm not familiar with the use and configuration of netbeans so I can't advise you how to actually make it work. You could try asking a separate question about this.