# C++ Opening file outside of directory via relative path not working

Tags: c++

[Opening a file in C++ outside of the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093891/opening-a-file-in-c-outside-of-the-working-directory)
Using the format of the code in this post, I tried to open a file using a relative path.

```
std::ifstream rules("/static/rules.txt");
```

Before I put "rules.txt" inside of folder "static", I was able to do this:

```
std::ifstream rules("rules.txt");
```

without error.

Comment: Path beginning with a `/` is absolute, at least in Linux. Try "static/rules.txt"

Comment: @Quimby That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Let say that your working directory is "/opt/usr1"
```

You have to take into account few elements:

```
1) Path to files

"/static/rules.txt"    <---Absolute path from root "/" folder, 
                           meaning that your code will look for file "/static/rules.txt"
"./static/rules.txt"   <---Relative path from working directory meaning that your    
                           code will look for file "/opt/usr1/static/rules.txt"
"rules.txt"            <---Relative path from working directory meaning that 
                           code will look for "/opt/usr1/rules.txt"


2) Ownership on folders and files, so check out what user 
   is running process and user privileges upon folders and files.
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

/static/rules.txt is the absolute path

rules.txt is a relative path, the file in the current directory

maybe you want to open the file std::ifstream rules("./static/rules.txt");   (notice the . in front of /static )

Comment: My bad, didn't completely understand the difference between relative/absolute paths.